# "Might" and "could" used for making suggestions

Tags: modal-verbs

In OALD, the 3rd definition of **might** is **used to make a polite suggestion**.

> You **might** try calling the help desk.
>
> I thought we **might** go to the zoo on Saturday.

While the 5th definition of **could** is **used to suggest something**.

> We **could** write a letter to the director.
>
> You **could** always try his home number.

I wonder if both usage is common in everyday speech. Which is preferred or more polite? Are they interchangeable in making suggestions?

Comment: Being curious what my grammar might say about this, I looked it up and found this great explanation: "We can use *could* to mean 'would be able to' and *might* to mean 'would perhaps' or 'would possible' -- PEU 258.6.

Comment: Are you suggesting that would be equivalent to: "It would be possible for you to write a letter to the director if I were to give my opinion"? @DamkerngT.

Comment: I think that might work too, in an uncommon context. Though it's rather wordy, a bit odd, and too literal (and by extension, non-idiomatic, imo), it still has a similar meaning to *"You could write a letter to the director."* No matter what its literal meaning is, it's still rather obvious that "You could write a letter to the director" is used as a suggestion.

Comment: That's just a way of paraphrase. I would never intend to say that in conversation. Do you agree might and could are both hypothetical here? @DamkerngT.

Comment: I believe that we could think of it as hypothetical thinking. (I believe that people think of *hypothetical* differently, even native speakers, though they usually arrive at a similar usage.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both perfectly correct and common in everyday speech. If there is a difference, it's a subtle one. "Might" is perhaps a bit more suggestive that the speaker's mind is open to other ideas, so I would call it *a bit* more polite. "Might" also feels slightly more informal, but that's just a gut feeling based on my particular experience. In that particular usage, the words are just about interchangeable. In the last example you would need to delete the word "always" to substitute "might" for "could".

The accepted answer here: [Difference between might and could](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/difference-between-might-and-could?rq=1) gets into other usages of the same words.

Comment: What you do think of the other answer?

Comment: It's an excellent answer to a slightly different question.

Comment: What will that question be?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment. Do you mean J.R.s answer in the link I posted as a part of my answer? Or user3169's answer here? If you meant the latter, I'd say that I don't really see the words as (s)he does, but as I said, the difference between the words in this context is very subtle. Even something like how your parents used the words could affect how you perceive them.

Comment: OK! And why would I need to delete "always" if I replaced "could" with "might"? @Jolenealaska

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng As far as I know, "could always" is just a bit of an oddity. It really just means the same as "could" (or "might", as we've discussed). I don't think there is any good reason for it, but "could always" is frequently used, "might always" isn't. At least not in this context. One way to look at it is to swap the words. "Always could" works, "always might" doesn't work as well.

Comment: Thx for your continuous revision:-D You really made youself understood.

Answer (score 1):

To me, *could* implies possible actions without any bias or personal interest. Just suggestions that are possible.

On the other hand, *might* has more of an implication of the speaker's personal involvement or interest in the suggestion. It's more than just a possibility, the speaker is saying something like "I personally want you to consider this".